# Excel VBA: Return mutiple non-unique cell contents (e.g. Given Name) to a ComboBox having searched on Surname

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Title says it.

I have a sheet containing student information - ID, Surname, Given Name, etc. I have a VBA form which successfully allows you to select a unique Surname which is passed to a different form if there are multiple rows in the sheet containing that Surname. I need to interrogate the sheet looking for that Surname and return the multiple Given Names to a ComboBox on the second form so the user can select the one they want.

Comment: Why would you need it? I think when you typed something in the ComboBox it auto selects the letter that matches what you type. What you need to do is just sort your source by Surname.

Comment: The issue is I need to select a second value (Given Name) having typed in a Surname. I thought a double-column Combobox would work but I can't see a way of seeing and selecting the second value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I did in 2008 but is still relevant to your request:

Create 2 sheets in a workbook called Names and FilteredNames

Create a form and call it FilterNames

On the form put a listbox and call it FilteredList

Above that put a textbox and call it UserFilter

Enter some names on the Names sheet and paste this code into the form's code area.

```
Private Sub UserFilter_Change()
Sheets("FilteredNames").Cells.ClearContents
For X = 1 To Sheets("Names").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If UCase(Left(Sheets("Names").Range("A" & X).Value, Len(UserFilter))) = UCase(UserFilter) Then
        If Sheets("FilteredNames").Range("A1") = "" Then
            Sheets("FilteredNames").Range("A1").Formula = Sheets("Names").Range("A" & X).Text
        Else
            Sheets("FilteredNames").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Formula = Sheets("Names").Range("A" & X).Text
        End If
    End If
Next
FilteredList.RowSource = "FilteredNames!A1:A" & Sheets("FilteredNames").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Now just run the form.

Do this to see how it works then you will just need to change the reference for input to be the list of surnames

Comment: Thanks for coming back so quick.

Comment: This returns the Surname - not the Given Name. Can you give me clue as to where to change the code to give me column B?

Answer (score 0):

Ok you may try this not so elegant solution. Say you have data like this:

[image]

Again, the list above is sorted. What we need to do is use the `RowSource` property of `ComboBox`.
 Now we need to get the range address to pass on the `RowSource` Property.
 We do that using below function:

```
Private Function GetGivenName(sname As String, Optional sh As Worksheet) As String
    If sh Is Nothing Then Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Dim fgname As Long, lgname As Long
    With sh
        fgname = .Range("A:A").Find(sname, [A1], , , , xlNext).Row
        lgname = .Range("A:A").Find(sname, [A1], , , , xlPrevious).Row
        GetGivenName = .Range("B" & fgname, "B" & lgname).Address(, , , True)
    End With
End Function
```

Then we use `UserForm` Initialize event to populate `ComboBox1`.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = _
        "'[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & Sheet1.Name & "'!" & "$A$2:$A$10"
End Sub
```

---

Then we use the function in setting the `ComboBox2` RowSource in `ComboBox1` After Update Event.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
    Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = _
        GetGivenName(Me.ComboBox1.Value, Sheet1)
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

In this example, the data is in a worksheet with codename `Sheet1`.
You can replace it with `Sheets("Sheet1")` or whatever name you got in your workbook. HTH.